# How to Generate a Texture to Make an Obstructing Plane Appear Invisible in a 3D Scene?

Tags: rendering, graphics, projection, perspective, projection-matrix

I have a 3D scene with a camera. Between the camera and the scene, I have a plane with arbitrary orientation. This plane obscures a portion of the scene from the camera’s perspective (anything behind the plane).

Now, let’s say that I want to generate an image at a specific resolution (say 1920x1080), such that if the image was applied as a texture on the plane, it would effectively make the plane invisible. i.e., the texture would contain the obscured part of the scene from the camera’s perspective, distorted based on the relative position and angles of the camera and the plane. This is much easier to explain with pictures…

Scene, obscured by plane from camera perspective:
[image: Scene, obscured by plane from camera perspective]

Portion of the camera view hidden by the plane:
[image: Portion of the camera view hidden by the plane]

Full resolution (distorted) image, which when applied to the plane would complete the scene from the camera perspective. **This is the image I want to compute**:
[image: This is the image I want to compute]

View from the camera with the image applied as a texture to the plane:
[image: View from the camera with the image applied as a texture to the plane]

To further clarify, if the camera moves the effect would be lost:
[image: To further clarify, if the camera moves the effect would be lost]

Please note: My goal is NOT just to achieve a transparent plane – I know there are many easy ways to do that. I’m actually interested in calculating the image that makes this effect possible in the way I have described, and this is just the simplest way I could think to describe it.

My intuition is that there should be a way to calculate a position for a second camera that would produce the image I want, or a way to calculate a custom projection matrix that would produce the image. My end goal is to do this in Unity, but at this stage I’m just looking for the theoretical explanation of how I can compute the image I need.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to take a snapshot of the scene without the plane from the original camera position, and then map that image to the plane using screenspace texture coordinates projected from that original camera. This will get you pixel perfection from the original camera's viewpoint, though a second camera might see more artifacts. If you want to prioritize the second camera's view (at the cost of sampling artifacts from the original camera's point of view), then we can go the more complex route. Is one or the other more suitable for your application?

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory. I might be misunderstanding your description, but wouldn't mapping the image from the camera to the plane this way result in a low(er) resolution image? The original camera only sees a small area of of the scene through the plane, so stretching this part of the image onto the plane would reduce quality. My end goal is to produce the third image in my question, at full resolution. I actualy don't need to map that image back to the plane, but I demonstrated doing this because it shows how I want that image to look. Thanks.

Comment: It would, from any other perspective. From the original camera's perspective, it gives a pixel perfect match, so the plane disappears entirely. That's why I wanted to check whether the goal was to prioritize perfect "transparent" matching from the original perspective or looking nice from other angles. So it sounds like you want to prioritize detail in the plane image when you see it dead-on. Are you potentially displaying this image on a separate monitor, or a tablet that can move?

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory. The latter case is what I'm after. You are exactly correct, the image will be displayed on a separate screen.

Comment: basically https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html but for 3D?